# How to select webElement present under form tag using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to click element present under Form tag in selenium web driver. using xpath, id, name it does not get recognized.refer screen shot[image: Image1 here you will see form tag details]

[image: In Image2 you willsee highlighted button id]

Comment: what have you tried so far? seems like ID is auto generated? is it dynamic, if so ask your developers to use unique and stable id for each and every element.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML. Please post HTML as text instead of images so they are more useful to the reader.

Comment: Also add a tag for the language that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a css selector:

```
.container-contact-info input[value='new']
```

Or an xpath

```
//*[@class='container-contact-info']//input[@value='new']
```

This might not work if you have a ton of these forms. If that's the case please update your question with the relevent information and I can adjust this answer.